# Hamburger button not responding, bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Somehow, after working fine for months (AFAIK), my hamburger button has stopped responding, and toggling a drop down menu. It seems so simple, I can't see what's changed - I would really appreciate it if someone can spot the error:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-md" id="navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-expand custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon custom-toggler navbar-toggler-icon-dark"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img
```

Could it be because there is no content in the bootstrap code?

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    content: "";
    background: no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
```

I can post more if necessary - thanks in advance !

Comment: I've helped you edit your code. Looks like there is some missing HTML content. Are you able to fix your snippet?

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your help, yes,  I can fix the code - what should I add?

Comment: You should add code that is able to reproduce the issue. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example